# Knockout basic validation with foreach array

Tags: validation, knockout.js, foreach

I'm relatively new to Knockout and development in general, I've done quite a bit of searching and I cant seem to get validation to work for arrays.
Basically I have a survey collection that contains a list of question and answer pairs in which I display with the below, when creating a new form the answers will be blank, when updating they should have existing data.

HMTL

```
  <table>
       <tbody data-bind="foreach: Survey">
          <tr>
            <td class="label" data-bind="text: Question"></td>
            <td class="value">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            <textarea style="width: 380px" rows="3" data-bind="value: Answer" class="ms-long" type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase"></textarea>
           </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have other fields which are not in this foreach loop which I can run validation on quite simply in the form of e.g.

```
self.FirstNameEx= self.FirstName.extend({ required: true });
```

However when I try to do the same with my "Answers" it doesnt work. Have tried below with no luck.

```
initDispatchingForm = function () {
var self = vm;   
self.FirstNameEx= self.FirstName.extend({ required: true });

//NONE OF BELOW WORK
//self.Survey= ko.observableArray(Survey);
//self.AnswerEx = self.Answer.extend({ required: true });
//self.Answer = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

self.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel, { deep: true });
ko.applyBindings(self);
```

Am I missing something really basic here?

Comment: well i made a necessary changes check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25116/ . hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that! mmm any idea how to get my collection of questions into self.Survey?

Comment: simple .you need to use arrayMap check this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25151/ . cheers

Comment: if you got your problem resolved i can post that as answer so you can mark it .later it will be helpful to someone .